# Python: name folder and file with variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath

I'm trying to create python script that will make folder with variable name and .csv file inside that folder with variable name included.

```
import pathlib
import csv
name = input()
pathlib.Path(name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
csvfile = open(name/name+"1day.csv", 'w', newline='')
```

Comment: use `os.path.join()` module to concatenate path instead of doing it they way you are doing. `import os` and `open(os.path.join(name, name + "1day.csv"), "w", newline="")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name/name` is you are trying to devide name by name. the `/` is not in a string but an operator.
There are two options to solve this.

1. Make the `/` string

   ```
   csvfile = open(name+"/"+name+"1day.csv", 'w', newline='')
   ```

   However, this option will cause issue if you want it to run in windows and
   Linux . So the option two is an notch up.
2. Use os.path.join()
   You have to import the os and use the the join to create a whole path.
   you script will look like the following

   ```
   import pathlib
   import csv
   import os # <--- new line 

   name = input()
   pathlib.Path(name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
   csvfile = open(os.path.join(name, name+"1day.csv"), 'w', newline='') # <--- changed one.
   ```

   The `os.path.join` will ensure to use right one (`/` or `\`) depending on the OS you are running.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there. Try

```
from pathlib import Path
import csv

name = input()
path = Path(name)
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
csvfile = open(path / (name + "1day.csv"), 'w', newline='')
```

instead.

The `Path` class is almost always the only thing you need from `pathlib`, so you don't need to import the *full* `pathlib`. If possible, I'd avoid using both, `os` and `pathlib`, at the same time for working with paths (not always possible, I know, but in most cases).